# The Google Distance Matrix API GPS coordinate search

Tags: python, google-maps

I'm trying to use the Google distance matrix API, and search the time to travel from one gps point to an other. I tried:

```
import urllib.request as url

API_KEY = "*********************"
orig_coord = "45.6492,4.7946"
dest_coord = "45.6403,4.7221"
mode = "bicycling"

url_request = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins={0}&destinations={1}s&mode={2}&language=fr-FR&key={3}".format(orig_coord, dest_coord, mode, API_KEY)

result = url.urlopen(url_request)
```

Here is what my result looks like:

```
{
   "destination_addresses" : [ "45 Claude Lane, Spartanburg, Caroline du Sud 29307, \xc3\x89tats-Unis" ],
   "origin_addresses" : [ "45.6492,4.7946" ],
    "rows" : [
      {
         "elements" : [
            {
               "status" : "ZERO_RESULTS"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}'
```

It looks like the API does not unerstand that I'm gaving GPS coordinate and not adress, thank's for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in your code. Here's the correct version.

```
url_request = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins={0}&destinations={1}&mode={2}&language=en-EN&key={3}".format(orig_coord, dest_coord, mode, API_KEY)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks good to me, unless your API_KEY is wrong.

Try this:

```
import requests


API_KEY = "*********************"
orig_coord = "45.6492,4.7946"
dest_coord = "45.6403,4.7221"
mode = "bicycling"

url_request = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins={0}&destinations={1}s&mode={2}&language=fr-FR&key={3}".format(orig_coord, dest_coord, mode, API_KEY)
rsp = requests.get(url_request)
print rsp.status_code
print rsp.text.encode('utf-8')
```

You will see data you want or error message.

Here is [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distancematrix/) for google distance matrix api. Hope it helps.

Comment: I have found it, it's just that I have added an "s" after duration. Anyway thank's for your help.